# Emulex OneConnect 10Gb Network Unclaimed

Tags: networking, centos, iscsi, nic, emulex

As a novice im hoping to gain a helping hand, Ive recently switched from windows server 2019 over to Centos 7 and the server has a 10gb Emulex OneConnect nic / card installed.

When using windows i was able to see the nic under the normal network devices and assign a static ip which was separate to my main network so i could get 10gb traffic to other servers.

Since moving over to centos im left pulling my hair out as i have no idea how to get the cards to work, Here is what i am currently seeing

```
> lshw -C network

  *-network:0 UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: OneConnect 10Gb NIC (be3)
   vendor: Emulex Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:15:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:97b00000-97b03fff memory:97a00000-97a1ffff memory:97a20000-97a3ffff memory:97b40000-97b7ffff


*-network:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: OneConnect 10Gb NIC (be3)
       vendor: Emulex Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:15:00.1
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:97b04000-97b07fff memory:97a40000-97a5ffff memory:97a60000-97a7ffff memory:97b80000-97bbffff
```

How does one change the interface from unclaimed?

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with this NIC in particular but it seems that it should use the be2net driver, can you confirm that driver is loaded? `lsmod | grep be2net` should show if the driver is loaded or not.